# VSTS Release - Azure Container Repository CD Trigger

Tags: docker, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-container-registry

Whenever a docker image is pushed to our Azure Container Registry, a Continuous Deployment is triggered. 
In addition to a specific ta, the latest tag is also included in the Image build, so what happens is that the release is trigged twice.

Is there any way to stop the CD from triggering if the tag equals latest?

Comment: Could you share how did you set the Trigger of your release definition?

Comment: On the Azure Container Repository artifact I created a CD trigger which triggers a release whenever an image of that specific repository is pushed. When enabling CD I see that a webhook is created in Azure on the repository and configured with a scope ( myexampleapp:* ). I tried playing with wildcards here but it doesn't accept that. In VSTS I cannot configure any artifact filters for that specific artifact.

Comment: Is there any build triggered? Could you share your build and release definition?

Comment: There is a CI build in another project. During the build phase the application gets built into a docker image and pushed into an Azure Container Registry. When the image is pushed my CD trigger is activated and will create the release and start deployment. This works perfectly but the only issue is that the trigger happens twice because in the build phase the image is also tagged with latest.

Answer (score 0):

I work in the VSTS team. I will like to take a look at the logs and help resolve the issue. Can you please contact me at https://twitter.com/AZooInMyLuggage

Atul Malaviya

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Atul, would you by any chance be able to share if you helpedDresse find a solution?